# How to paste contents of a register specifying a line number?

Tags: vim

Assume a text file with 5 lines, each having a line break. This text file is opened in gvim. While in command mode and cursor in line number 1, the content of current line is yanked into default register.

How to paste/put yanked to different line number without moving the cursor? For example, cursor is in line number 1. Yanked content should be put in line number 4. How to do this in gvim without moving the cursor to line number 4?

Comment: I dont have exactly an answer for you but you could always do something like move to the line you want to paste to, lets say line 3, ```:3``` than copy a line, lets say line 5: ```:5y``` ENTER ```p```. Now your at line 3 sure but you can always just go right back to your last cursor location with <code> `` </code>

Comment: I don't know exactly how to do it but you can try with something like this:
```:4s/$/\r("your-registry)/g``` (it won't work bcs I don't know how to use registry in command mode)
but it'll move your cursor so the simplest way I know is to just move to line 4 with `4gg`, paste it and with `p` and go back to last position with `''` (two apostrophes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The cursor position is an important part of command addressing**; for interactive editing, it does not make sense to have commands that work "at a distance". (Inside Vimscript you can use low-level functions like `setline()` to modify arbitrary places, but that should not be part of normal use, and here I disagree with @SergioAraujo's answer, which presents this command as suitable for interactive use.)

Instead, Vim makes it easy to temporarily go to a location and then return back to where you came from. The [`:help jumplist`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#jumplist) and especially [`CTRL-O`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#CTRL-O) are for that. Your example paste you be done via `4Gp<C-O>` or ``` 4Gp`` ```; to use Ex commands, you have to explicitly set the jump point: ``` m':4put<CR>`` ```. The advantage of working with the jumplist is that the paste target now also became part of it, so you can easily go forward (with `<C-I>`) to it, too.

Comment: Ingo, see my answer—vim provides interactive commands at a distance (which use command addressing at its true roots, Ex). It does indeed make sense sometimes... it is here the simplest solution

Answer (score 0):

Here an example:

```
 :call setline(4, getline(4) . " " . @")
```

We are setting line 4 to line 4 itself plus space " "
plus default register @" .

Just In case you want just put the content 
of the line 1 on the line 4 type:

```
:call setline(4, getline(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:t` command (a synonym for `:copy`). Examples:

```
:1t 4
:.t 4
```

Comment: `:to` expands to `:topleft`; you have to use `:t` or `:co[py]`.

Comment: These Ex commands still move the cursor to the target location (and bypass the register), not what OP asked for.

Comment: @IngoKarkat really? For some reason I had it in my head they didn’t; it makes sense they do, though.